# Install Error WebSphere MQ V7.01.6 Data1.Cab in Use

Tags: ibm-mq

I am unable to install IBM WebSphere MQ V7.01.6.  When I install I am getting the following error:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

The title in the dialog is .\DATA1.CAB

I have tried running as administrator.  I click OK and then it just locks up.  I let it stay locked up overnight and then I had to do a force restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there is a bug with the installer.  The fix is is to choose Custom Installation with all the default options.

Here are links talking about the installer bug:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21397589

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21654327

http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=30377

Comment: No, those links talk about (various) different issues - none of those would appear as a data1.cab issue, which I have never seen. (I've debugged files in use, hangs etc and one of those links is a useful one talking about various issues plus how to debug things - I helped produce it!)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, try copying the media locally and running the install from there. If that fails try the traditional reboot just in case. If that fails, use process explorer and 'search' by 'data1.cab' and see who has an open handle on it. If that fails, try using process monitor to log up until the error and see what you actually get.

How far into the install does it fail... immediately or after a while? If it at least starts, the other thing to do is to enable MSI logging (See microsoft fixit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300, which turns on logging and in your temporary directory (%temp%) you get a log file... I am suspicious you are not getting into the msi part yet.

Bear in mind there might be other things opening the file such as indexers, virus scanners, backups etc so it might be a case of setting process monitor to log for access just to the file and see who hits it.